# separate the post of a category by subcategory

Tags: posts, loop

I'm dynamically generating my category post by getting the Page title and match it with the category name. The category I'm posting sometimes has a subcategory now I need to separate this subcategory by groups. I'm using this code.

```
<ul>
<?php 
    global $post;
    $post_slug = get_the_title(); 
    $args = array ( 'category_name' => $post_slug, 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => title, 'order' => ASC);
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li>
        <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I need to call my category only by using the page title. since I'm using a template that post different category and controlling it by name title of the page. Not quite sure if I can convert that to `category => ID`

Please see link [here](http://prntscr.com/by26xn) for the explanation and mock

Found this [thread](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/display-subcategories-on-category-pages-in-wordpress/) not sure if its going to fit on what I did? also this [one](https://yoast.com/showing-subcategories-on-wordpress-category-pages/)

Comment: Do not cross post please

Comment: @PieterGoosen what do you mean?

Comment: Exactly what I'm saying, do not post your question across multiple stacks

Comment: Did you try any of the solutions in the links you cite? What happened?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_term_by`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) to get a category by `name`-

```
$category = get_term_by( 'name', $post_slug, 'category' );
echo $category->term_id;
```

Comment: Just a note, this is not reliable as you can have duplicate term names across the entire hierarchy is a given hierarchical taxonomy. One should always try and avoid using term names in queries

Comment: I already have a solution about that. what I need is control the post of 1 category by separating them or grouping them according to the sub-category. e.g Category 1 under it Subcategory1 and Subcategory2. right now I dont have any filter for the subcategories.

Comment: sorry, I have no clue what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your parent post/category loop use this to generate a list of post titles/category names of the child posts/categories:

```
$taxonomy_name = 'category';
$this_term = get_term_by( 'name', get_the_title(), $taxonomy_name );

$term_id = $this_term->term_id;
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {//get the children and search the posts by title

  $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
  $args = array ( 'post_title' => $term->name, 'orderby' => title, 'order' => ASC);
  $myposts = get_posts( $args );
  foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li>
      <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>

}
echo '</ul>';
```

UPDATE:
Let's try that again. Inside your parent post/category loop use this . . .

```
$taxonomy_name = 'category';
$this_term = get_term_by( 'name', get_the_title( get_the_ID() ), $taxonomy_name );

$categories = get_categories( array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'child_of'  => $this_term->term_ID,
    ) );

if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) {

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        $this_post = get_page_by_title( $category->name, OBJECT, 'post');
        echo '<h3>' . $this_post ->post_title . '</h3>';

    }
}
```

Comment: This is expensive and overboard

Comment: what I;m going to use to wrap this up?

Comment: I guess I'm a little uncear on what you're trying to achieve. You have post titles that are category names. This lists the children of those categories. I display the name of the child category using the corresponding $this_post->post_title. What output are you looking for?

Comment: Code I'm using is getting the page name then convert it to slugs with has a corresponding same value as categories. now after that some of the main categories have subcategories i want it to seperate depending on what subcategories it belong if it has.

Comment: When you say 'I what it to seperate depending . . . ' What is 'it' refering too? Are you just trying to list the child categories based on a given category slug?

Comment: I'm displaying the post  by its Category the Category has a category under it. so the main category has to be seperated by the subcategory though it is being called by the main category only.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Maybe a mock up of the output you're looking for would help?

Comment: Please see the link for further explanationhttp://prntscr.com/by26xn

Comment: If you put my UPDADTE code inside your foreach loop and you'll get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Did this before for a website. Here's what i did:
Checked if there is a category with the same name as the title:

```
if( term_exists(get_the_title(), 'category' ))
```

If there was one then I got the category by slug:

```
$cat = get_term_by("slug", $post->post_name, "category");
```

Checked if category had parent or was a parent:

```
if($cat->parent !== 0) {
    $catID = $cat->parent;
} else {
    $catID = $cat->term_id;
}
```

Then retrieved categories by said parent:

```
$args = array(
                'type'                      => 'post',
                'child_of'                  => $catID,
                'hide_empty'                  => false,
                'hierarchical'              => true,
                'exclude'                   => '1'
            );
$categories = get_categories($args);
```

Then a simple loop with links:

```
foreach($categories as $categorie) {
    if($categorie->slug == $post->post_name) {
        $clasa = "class='current'";
    } else {
        $clasa = "";
    }
    echo "<a ".$clasa." href='".home_url("/").$slug."/".$categorie->slug."'>".$categorie->name."</a>";
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't knew how. I need to learn these things. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: got syntax error with this. I don't know much about php.